# Views duplicates cause of linking two content types "Author" and "publications"

Tags: views

I have created an "author" content type, with, for the moment, these fields:

```
First Name:
Second Name:
e-mail address:
```

I also created "publications" content type with field reference to the author's names from "author" content type.
Now, I am trying to get an "authors" view which shows author's name, email address, and, I want to show the list of documents for each author.

[Screenshot http://drupalfr.org/sites/default/files/Untitled-1.jpg](http://drupalfr.org/sites/default/files/Untitled-1.jpg)

So, I linked the author's node title to "content referencing content from field_publication_author" with a Link this field to the original piece of content through a relationship

When I did this, I got duplicate entries for author name when there is more than one document referenced to this author.
I have tried to change query settings, but without success.
When i aggregate the field that shows the documents, I have only one result instead of getting a list of documents.

Could anyone help me ?